# Strange - ALL applications suddenly "forgot" their credentials

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login, credentials

Even with years of troubleshooting, I'm not sure how this is even possible. Today, I logged into my Windows 7 account on my personal computer and it appears that all applications that required passwords forgot their passwords.

Dropbox asked me for my email address and password to link my account
Chrome requested my sync passphrase
Outlook asked for the password to all 3 of my email accounts
Skype asked me for my password
VPN connections asked me for passwords
Network drives asked me for passwords

And many more. All of these applications were set to save passwords and have never acted like this before. Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior? I'm pretty sure not all of these services rely on it, but could it be an issue with the Windows Credential Storage?

Comment: It sounds like the user's profile was wiped.  None of those services us `Windows Credential Storage` even indirectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Ramhound's hunch is correct (Your user profile has been wiped). You could try restoring from a backup, if you have one. If not, a `Windows System Restore` *might* help.

Comment: ...and trying a System Restore certainly can't *hurt*, so go for it.